# The request was aborted: Could not create SSL/TLS secure channel in c#

Tags: c#, httpclient, httpwebrequest, tls1.2, webview2

While trying to execute below code in windows server 2008 r2 it's throwing error as 'The request was aborted: Could not create SSL/TLS secure channel'. We have already enabled TLS 1.1 and 1.2. Please tell us how can we solve it. Also while trying to hit same url in IE its giving error for TLS 1.1, 1.2 is not enabled. Also can we do request and response with using webview2.

```
string sURL = "https://connect.medlineplus.gov/service?mainSearchCriteria.v.cs=2.16.840.1.113883.6.88&mainSearchCriteria.v.c=897294&knowledgeResponseType=application/json";

ServicePointManager.SecurityProtocol = SecurityProtocolType.Tls12 | SecurityProtocolType.Tls11 | SecurityProtocolType.Tls;
WebRequest request = WebRequest.Create(sURL);
request.Credentials = CredentialCache.DefaultCredentials;

request.Method = "GET";

WebResponse response = request.GetResponse();

// Get the stream containing content returned by the server.
Stream dataStream = response.GetResponseStream();

// Open the stream using a StreamReader for easy access.
StreamReader reader = new StreamReader(dataStream);

// Read the content.
sReponseInJson = reader.ReadToEnd();
dataStream.Close();
```

HttpWebRequest, httpclient and WebRequest.

---

**

> From medlineplus.gov the issue gets resolved. They have made cipher
> security-related changes and now able to use above request on Win 2008
> R2 also.

**

Comment: `ServicePointManager.SecurityProtocol =` why are you doing this? And why are you still using 2008R2 when it's way out of date, have you at least applied all security patches and have you enabled TLS 1.2 in the registry as documented  https://support.microsoft.com/en-us/topic/update-to-enable-tls-1-1-and-tls-1-2-as-default-secure-protocols-in-winhttp-in-windows-c4bd73d2-31d7-761e-0178-11268bb10392

Comment: As of now, we can not upgrade OS. Also, we have already enabled TLS 1.2 in registry as well.

Comment: And what version of .NET are you on? Exact build number please.

Comment: We are using .Net 4.8 Also, we have tried 4.5, 4.6, 4.6.1 etc

Comment: What happens when you use `HttpClient` instead

Comment: YES I have tried that also same issue

Comment: Are you sure you installed all the latest updates, and enabled TLS 1.2 and all the correct ciphers? Did you use the IIS Crypto to check? I suggest you use a Wireshark trace to see what the Server Hello and Client Hello packets look like, there is clearly a mismatch in ciphers between them. Judging from the results from https://www.ssllabs.com/ssltest/analyze.html?d=connect.medlineplus.gov&s=75.2.125.67&hideResults=on it looks like you need to enable the ECDH ciphers.

Comment: Yes we have tried same still no luck

Comment: From medlineplus.gov the issue gets resolved. They have made cipher security-related changes and now able to use above request on Win 2008 R2 also.

Answer (score 0):

As you can see here:

https://www.ssllabs.com/ssltest/analyze.html?d=connect.medlineplus.gov&s=75.2.125.67&hideResults=on

the website you're trying to connect to, has disabled every security protocol, except tls 1.2. So, you have to do the same:

```
ServicePointManager.SecurityProtocol = SecurityProtocolType.Tls12;
```

Comment: Yes tried same only with SecurityProtocolType.Tls12
but still issue exists.

Comment: This is not the answer. `ServicePointManager.SecurityProtocol` should not be messed around with, the operating system will deal with it automatically. It's the operating system that is the issue here, it needs to be configured for TLS 1.2 and ECDH.

Comment: `the operating system will deal with it automatically` - I wish you were correct, but sadly, no. Have you ever tried using these older versions of windows server? It might be rather tricky to get Tls1.2 to work there. It will default to whatever but the latest and most secure tls.

Comment: @HirasawaYui Yes I have, and all you need to do is install the latest updates, enable TLS 1.2 and ciphers in the registry (or with IIS Crypto), and use an up to date version of .NET, and then everything just works.